# xml equivalent flag for launchmode="singletask"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, flags

We would like to add a flag using Java while starting an Activity. But we cannot find the equivalent of setting launchmode="single task" equivalent flag.
thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a combination of [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) and [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

From the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` documentation:

> if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().
>
> ...
>
> This launch mode can also be used to good effect in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to start the root activity of a task, it will bring any currently running instance of that task to the foreground, and then clear it to its root state. This is especially useful, for example, when launching an activity from the notification manager.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the following combination;

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Hope this helps!